# Excel Formula show with result as well as

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, desktop-computer, checksum, winetricks

I have a sheet with:

```
A  B  C
7  5  =A1+B1
```

So, C1=12.

Is it possible that D1 shows the numbers `5`,`7` used in the sum in `C1`?

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you are asking. Please reword your question to better explain what you are attempting to do.

Comment: So, do you want to basically *show* the formula in D1, and *use* the formula in C1?

Answer (score 2):

You simply use the CONCATENATE function:

```
=CONCATENATE(A1,"+",B1)
```

Or you can use the concatenate operator:

```
=A1 & "+" & B1
```

In both cases the numeric cells are converted to strings automatically.

Following the suggestions in the comments, you can combine the calculation and the result in the same cell:

```
=A1 & "+" & B1 & "=" & (A1+B1)
```

In all cases you may want to set right alignment for the cell, which is the default for numbers, but not for text.

Comment: Maybe it'd also have a `"=",SUM(A1,B1)` included. `=CONCATENATE(A1,"+",B1,"=",SUM(A1,B1))` or, alternatively, `=A1&"+"&B1&"="&A1+B1`

Comment: @EngineerToast - Yes, of course. I would normally use `&`, but I thought the CONCATENATE function needed less explanation.

Comment: You may want to edit your answer to include the suggestion. Given the nature of this site, too much explanation is better than lack of details.